# Custom RSS Reader for Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rss-reader

I need below kind of out put after reading the rss feed from the blog feed.

[image]

I have written below code snippet for that.

```
private IEnumerable<RssReader> GetBlogRssFeeds()
        {

           var rssFeed = XDocument.Load("http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss");

             var rssFeedOut= from item in rssFeed.Descendants("item")
               select new RssReader
               {
                   Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                   Link = item.Element("link").Value,
                   Description = (item.Element("description") != null) ? Regex.Match(item.Element("description").Value, @"^.{1,180}\b(?<!\s)").Value : ""
               };

        return rssFeedOut;
        }
```

**View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" ContentType="text/html" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<RssReader>>" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <table border="1">

    <% foreach (var p in Model)
       { %>
    <tr border="1">
        <th>
            <%= Html.Encode(p.Title) %>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr border="1">
        <th>
            <%= Html.Encode(p.Description) %>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr border="1">
        <th>
            <%= Html.Encode(p.Link) %>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
           </asp:Content>
```

But my Final out put shows everything is as below.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now my View is as below.

[image]

**My Question :** How can I show Images and content are as above image ?

**Updated Question :** How can I get the description without html tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your content type is `application/rss+xml`. In that way it will never show up as html.

Just remove the `ContentType="application/rss+xml"` part or replace it with `text/html` and change your page to be html instead of rss.

There is no way to tell the browser: hey, you should read rss but format it like html. You can [combine things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782116/where-can-i-find-a-stylesheet-for-rss-feeds) (so rss tags in your html), but it will evaluate the way the browser thinks best (and that is not what you want).

Just output html from your rss reading and format it as html.

Comment: Please check my 'Updated Question' above ?

Comment: Put the image inside a `img` tag, etc. just like in html.

Comment: Remove the `Html.Encode` to enable direct entering html code into the result.

Comment: But my question is how to filter the html tags which are coming with the description as I showed on my last image (2nd row is the description)?